# Ubuntu WSL2 could not resolve hostname for GIT clone

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have gitlab local repository and VPN to connect with it. I already installed WSL and it worked well before with clone repository (I've done add ssh pub). After updating kernel from WSL and change to WSL2. I cannot clone repository anymore and it returns:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.local.id: Name or service not
> known

I've done creating `/etc/wsl.conf` file

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = true
```

and `/etc/resolv.conf` file

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

**NOTE:
I can clone repo through GIT Bash**

Restart the WSL, terminal and even reboot laptop. But still cannot clone the repository through SSH. I followed others suggestion but still no luck. Maybe your suggestion may help. many thanks!

Comment: Is the hostname suffix literally `.local.id`, or just `.local`?

Comment: It's actually `local.name.id` for the suffix

Comment: @Hasturkun `gitlab.local.id` is a perfectly valid address: https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/gitlab.local.id; [`.id`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.id) is a top-level domain for Indonesia.

Comment: Full hostname was `gitlab.local.name.id` and it's adjusted by company

Comment: `gitlab.local.name.id` — that name doesn't resolve, at least for me.

Comment: `name` on that domain just imitating the real one. The real domain does not resolve on that dns.net as well because its deployed on private local on-prem server, need VPN provided by company to access it. Somehow its worked well before I update the kernel and WSL2 (I can clone the repo). Unfortunately, now that no resolve any hostname, even when update it does not resolve any host linux apt-get. After getting done with setup above now it's work but still no luck with SSH to clone the repo.

Comment: Have you tried to add a local DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: @phd: I realize, I was trying to understand if it was supposed to resolve via mDNS. Dhody, Is it possible that you need to use an internal DNS server? Also maybe check if things work outside the VPN and see comments on [this WSL issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1350), and [the WSL troubleshooting guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#wsl-has-no-network-connectivity-once-connected-to-a-vpn). Also, https://superuser.com/q/1630487

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git (and almost nothing to do with ssh): it's an OS and/or DNS issue. In this case ssh is using whatever resolver comes with your WSL setup, and apparently that wasn't quite right, based on "reinstalling fixed it".

Comment: @torek thats right. Git has nothing to do with the problem, but the problem causing git and other servername does not resolve. The problem begun with updating the kernel then change the wsl version in the middle of working on current distro

Answer (score 0):

It took me almost 3 days to try others workaround to solve it and it's just solved by **re-installed the updated distro**. I have no clue why origin `resolv.conf` (generated by WSL) before was gone after updated to WSL2 and suddenly does not resolve any hostname.

After re-install distro and re-added new SSH key to gitlab, WSL generate new `resolv.conf` file and git back to works again.

**UPDATE:**

As per request from @Philippe, The new `resolve.conf`:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.19.144.1
```

This configuration comes automatically and without wsl.conf at `/etc/` directory.

**NOTES:**
Please make sure you working on the right WSL version before you doing something on your distro or you will probably ended up with the same problem above.

Comment form @torek above was right. **Git has nothing to do with the problem**, but the problem causing git and other servername does not resolve. My problem begun with updating the kernel then change the wsl version in the middle of working on current distro.

Comment: Is it possible to post the new version of `resolv.conf` (redacted as necessary) ?